# why does it say 'comma is not valid at this position' (position indicated below)

Tags: mysql, syntax

the error warning is shown on the third line 'title_id'

```
CREATE TABLE books(
book_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
title_id, #it gives the error warning here.
publisher_id,
author_id,
book_type VARCHAR (50), #aka ebook/hard/paper
genre_id,
FOREIGN KEY(genre_id) REFERENCES genres(genre_id),
FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES author(author_id),
FOREIGN KEY(publisher_id) REFERENCES publishers(publisher_id),
FOREIGN KEY(title_id) REFERENCES title(title_id));
```

i haven't actually created the table yet. i'm not exactly sure what's up with it

Comment: You are not defining a type

Comment: Add datatypes to all columns

Comment: Datatypes are not optional in MySQL like they are in SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

You have encountered an error because you haven't specified the data type for the "title_id" and some other columns. To resolve this issue try this:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    book_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    title_id INT,  -- Specify the data type (INT) here
    publisher_id INT,
    author_id INT,
    book_type VARCHAR(50),
    genre_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genres(genre_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author(author_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publishers(publisher_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (title_id) REFERENCES title(title_id)
);
```